Lint giving heap errors despite extending heap
I have 54 Typescript files (31 src and 23 test). I've tried up to 8192 heap size, and cannot help but get a heap error running
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js .

Oddly, as I tried running eslint, it kept giving me linting errors, which I kept fixing until it no longer complained. However, now that it stopped complaining about linting errors, it gives me the heap error:
$ node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js .

<--- Last few GCs --->

[421053:0x4295c4c0]    58454 ms: Mark-Compact 8075.2 (8232.6) -> 8063.6 (8236.6) MB, 1675.44 / 0.05 ms  (average mu = 0.464, current mu = 0.016) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
[421053:0x4295c4c0]    61065 ms: Mark-Compact 8080.4 (8237.6) -> 8068.7 (8241.9) MB, 2581.08 / 0.04 ms  (average mu = 0.246, current mu = 0.011) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0xb86ecf node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 2: 0xef74d0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 3: 0xef77b7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
 4: 0x1109355  [node]
 5: 0x11211d8 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 6: 0x10f72f1 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 7: 0x10f8485 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 8: 0x10d5ad6 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
 9: 0x1531906 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x7fd85ded9ef6 
Aborted (core dumped)

This is my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "watchOptions": {
    // Use native file system events for files and directories
    "watchFile": "useFsEvents",
    "watchDirectory": "useFsEvents",
    // Poll files for updates more frequently
    // when they're updated a lot.
    "fallbackPolling": "dynamicPriority",
    // Don't coalesce watch notification
    "synchronousWatchDirectory": true,
    // Finally, two additional settings for reducing the amount of possible
    // files to track  work from these directories
    "excludeDirectories": ["**/node_modules"]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "outDir": "." //"./dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strict": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.unit-test.ts",
    "test/**/*.integration-test.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

This is my .eslintrc.cjs file:
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    extraFileExtensions: ['.d.ts']
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
  ],
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    // Enable Prettier rules and display as ESLint errors
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        printWidth: 100,
        semi: true, // Require semicolons
        singleQuote: true, // Use single quotes
        trailingComma: 'none', // No trailing commas
        useTabs: false // Use spaces instead of tabs
      }
    ],

    // General rules
    'no-console': ['warn', { allow: ['debug','info', 'warn', 'error'] }],
    'no-debugger': 'error',
    'no-bitwise': 'error',
    'no-caller': 'error',
    'no-new-wrappers': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [
      'error',
      {
        varsIgnorePattern: '^_', // Allow unused variables starting with _
        argsIgnorePattern: '^_' // Allow unused arguments starting with _
      }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/array-type': ['error', { default: 'array' }], // Prefer 'string[]' over 'Array<string>'
    '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions': ['error', 'interface'], // Prefer 'interface' over 'type'
    '@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style': [
      'error',
      {
        multiline: {
          delimiter: 'semi',
          requireLast: true
        },
        singleline: {
          delimiter: 'semi',
          requireLast: true
        }
      }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/member-ordering': [
      'error',
      {
        default: [
          'static-field',
          'instance-field',
          'abstract-field',
          'constructor',
          'static-get',
          'instance-get',
          'abstract-get',
          'static-set',
          'instance-set',
          'abstract-set',
          'static-method',
          'instance-method',
          'abstract-method'
        ]
      }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of': 'error', // Prefer for-of loops
    '@typescript-eslint/semi': ['error', 'always'], // Require semicolons
    '@typescript-eslint/space-before-function-paren': [
      'error',
      {
        anonymous: 'always',
        named: 'never',
        asyncArrow: 'always'
      }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/quotes': ['error', 'single', { avoidEscape: true }], // Use single quotes
    '@typescript-eslint/unified-signatures': 'error', // Combine function overloads

    // Import rules
    /*
    'import/order': 
    [
      'error',
      {
        'newlines-between': 'always',
        alphabetize: {
          order: 'asc'
        },
        groups: [
          ['builtin', 'external', 'internal'],
          ['parent', 'sibling', 'index']
        ]
      }
    ],
    */
    'import/no-duplicates': 'warn', // Warn about duplicate imports
    'import/no-unresolved': 'error', // Error on unresolved imports

    // Style rules

    'object-shorthand': ['error', 'consistent'],      // Enforce consistent object shorthand
    'quote-props': ['error', 'consistent-as-needed'], // Only quote object keys when required
    radix: 'error',                                   // Enforce radix parameter for parseInt
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never']                // Disallow trailing commas
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['src/**/*.ts','test/**/*.unit-test.ts', 'test/**/*.integration-test.ts'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off'
      }
    }
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['node_modules/', 'dist/'], // Ignore unnecessary directories
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {
        project: './tsconfig.json' // Use TypeScript project for import resolution
      }
    }
  }
};


This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "src/app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=4096' npx jest --verbose --passWithNoTests --Match=*/test/*",
    "coverage": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=4096' npx jest --coverage --verbose --passWithNoTests --Match=*/test/*",
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "lint": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=4096' npx eslint --ext .ts .",
    "clean": "tsc --build --clean && (rm -r -f cdk.out || true) && (rm -r -f dist || true)",
    "watch": "tsc-watch --onSuccess 'npm run dev'",
    "dev": "npm run clean && npm run update-cdk && npm run lint && npm run test && npm run synth --env=dev",
    "synth": ". ./env-${npm_config_env}.env && npx cdk synth *-${APP_ENV}",
    "local-lambda": "SAM_CLI_TELEMETRY=0 sam local invoke -e \"${npm_config_event}\" -t ./cdk.out/${USER}-MMPS-stateless-dev.template.json --invoke-image public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20 \"${npm_config_lambda}\" ",
    "bootstrap": ". ./env-${npm_config_env}.env && npx cdk bootstrap aws://${AWS_ACCOUNT}/${AWS_REGION} --trust \"${AWS_DEPLOY_ACCOUNT}\" --cloudformation-execution-policies \"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess\" ",
    "deploy": ". ./env-${npm_config_env}.env && npx cdk deploy --app cdk.out *-${APP_SERVICE}-${npm_config_stack:-*}-${APP_ENV} --require-approval never ",
    "destroy": ". ./env-${npm_config_env}.env && npx cdk destroy --app cdk.out *-${APP_ENV} --require-approval never ",
    "update-cdk": "npm install --save-dev aws-cdk@latest && npm install aws-cdk-lib@latest",
    "get-env-prop-value": ". ./env-${npm_config_env}.env && printenv \"${npm_config_property}\"",
    "get-postgres-endpoint": ". ./env-${npm_config_env}.env && aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name=${APP_NAMESPACE}-${APP_SERVICE}-postgres-${APP_ENV} | jq -r '.Stacks[0].Outputs[] | select(.OutputKey == \"ClusterEndpoint\") | .OutputValue' ",
    "get-stack-outputs": ". ./env-${npm_config_env}.env && aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name=${APP_NAMESPACE}-${APP_SERVICE}-${npm_config_stack}-${APP_ENV} | jq -r '.Stacks[0].Outputs[]' "
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.146",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^22.10.2",
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.18.0",
    "aws-cdk": "^2.173.0",
    "esbuild": "^0.24.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.31.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.6.0",
    "gulp": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "^3.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsc-watch": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge": "^3.709.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-ssm": "^3.709.0",
    "aws-cdk-lib": "^2.173.0",
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
    "constructs": "^10.4.2",
    "pg": "^8.13.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "zod": "^3.24.1"
  }
}

